# Proving that $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not formally real.

Tags: field-theory, absolute-value, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory, nonstandard-analysis

I've been looking for a concrete proof without results. The only hint that I have found says:

1) $\mathbb{Q}_2$ contains a square root of $-7$.

2) $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ($p>2$) contains a square root of $1-p$.

**Question 1:** How to prove 1 and 2? if it is very long to write as an answer, is there any book or paper showing the proof?

**Question 2:** Is there any better way to prove that $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not formally real?

Comment: Use Hensel's lemma.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the binomial theorem (with exponent a half; write $-7$ as $1 - 8$).

Comment: For $p>3$, it’s easily seen, without Hensel nor Binomial Series, that $\Bbb Q_p$ contains the $(p-1)$-th roots of unity. Start with any $p$-adic unit, say $n$, and take $p$-th powers, successively. You get a sequence  $p$-adically convergent to the root of unity that’s $\equiv n\pmod p$. (The method works for $p=2,3$ as well, it’s just that the roots of unity there are real.)

Comment: Hi @QiaochuYuan  for sake of completeness, I would like to accept an answer for this question. Do you want to post one?

Comment: Hi @Lubin do you want to post an answer for sake of completeness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sketch of the three approaches suggested in the comments.

1. You want to know whether the equation $x^2 - a$ has solutions in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, for $a = 1 - 8$ when $p = 2$ and for $a = 1 - p$ when $p \ge 3$. You can first show that these equations have solutions $\bmod 8$ and $\bmod p$ respectively, then apply [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) repeatedly to show that these solutions lift to solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ respectively.
2. The binomial theorem with exponent $\frac{1}{2}$ gives $(1 + x)^{1/2} = \sum_{n \ge 0} {1/2 \choose n} x^n$, and this equation continues to make sense over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ provided that the RHS converges $p$-adically, which it does when $x = -8$ and $p = 2$ (this requires a little work to bound the $2$-adic valuation of ${1/2 \choose n}$) and when $x = -p$ and $p \ge 3$ (this is easy because ${1/2 \choose n} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ in this case).
3. Lubin's suggestion, which directly addresses the formal realness question, is to use the [Teichmuller character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller_character) $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^{p^n}$ to show that $\mathbb{Q}_p$ contains all $(p-1)$th roots of unity. When $p \ge 5$ we get roots of unity which don't exist in any formally real field.

Answer (score 4):

The sketch by @QiaochuYuan of my suggestion about taking successive $p$-th powers is good enough for me.

But my method of seeing that $\sqrt{-7}\in\Bbb Q_2$ is this. Start with $f(X)=X^2+7$, form $F(X+1)=X^2+2X+8$, and notice that the Newton polygon plots the points $(0,3)$, $(1,1)$, and $(2,0)$ so that there are two segments of width $1$, thus two $\Bbb Q_2$-rational factors of degree one.

If you aren’t comfortable with Newton, just form $F(2X+1)=4X^2+4X+8=4(X^2+X+2)$, which has a root by any version of Hensel that you like.